# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IMPORT_BEAN_NAME_GENERATOR

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a unit test with the following annotations:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
```

I use Spring Boot 2.2.0 and Spring 5.2.0 and Junit Jupiter. The test tests a dao class using an in-memory H2 database. This used to work before I switched to spring boot 2.2.0. 
I get an error

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IMPORT_BEAN_NAME_GENERATOR
```

When I debug I see

```
@Override
@Deprecated
public void registerBeanDefinitions(AnnotationMetadata metadata, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
    registerBeanDefinitions(metadata, registry, ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.IMPORT_BEAN_NAME_GENERATOR);
}
```

in class RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport. I get the exception on `registerBeanDefinitions`. The method is Deprecated, the documentation says it is replaced by a method with three arguments [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.html). When I set a breakpoint in `ConfigurationClassPostProcessor` where `IMPORT_BEAN_NAME_GENERATOR` is defined, the code doesn't get there. Apparently, something is using the old method but I can't find out what is. When I go back to spring boot 2.1.8, I don't get this error.

Comment: These error come from either mixing jars from different framework versions or using incompatible version of frameworks, like too new Spring Data JPA with old Spring framework or vice-versa.

Comment: I read your comment on a similar issue. I checked all dependencies, I can't find non matching versions. I set the versions of spring and spring boot in properties in the main pom, other poms refer to those properties. I will double check.

Comment: You were right. Checking again showed one place where a version was specified where it shouldn't be.

Comment: You shouldn't set the Spring version, that should be managed by Spring Boot. Also you should really be using the spring boot starters and not include manual dependencies. Hence you are probably using an incompatible Spring Data or whatever this exception triggers dependency. Probably due to not using starters but rather plain dependencies.

Comment: Can you turn your comments into an answer?