# NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.util.TypeInformation.isSubTypeOf(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z

Tags: java, elasticsearch, nested, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Spring Data Elasticsearch with Elasticsearch version 7.4. 
Maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Model

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Document(indexName = "address", createIndex = true)
public class Address {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String fullAddress;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested, store = true)
    private List<Entry> parts;

    public Address(String fullAddress) {
        this.fullAddress = fullAddress;
    }

    public Address(String fullAddress, List<Entry> entryList) {
        this.fullAddress = fullAddress;
        this.parts = entryList;
    }
}

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Entry {
    private String aoid;
    private String aoGuid;
    private String code;
    private String offName;
    private String parentGuid;
    private String shortName;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Integer)
    private Integer aoLevel;
    private String postalCode;
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface AddressElasticRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Address, String> {
    List<Address> findByFullAddressContains(String fullAddress);
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class SearchServiceImpl implements SearchService {
    private final AddressElasticRepository addressElasticRepository;

    public SearchServiceImpl(AddressElasticRepository addressElasticRepository) {
        this.addressElasticRepository = addressElasticRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Document> search(String query) {
        List<Address> all = addressElasticRepository.findByFullAddressContains(query);
        all.forEach(it -> log.info("-- " + it.getFullAddress()));

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Address address) {
        addressElasticRepository.save(address);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class SearchController {
    private final SearchService searchService;

    public SearchController(SearchService searchService) {
        this.searchService = searchService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/fias/search", method = GET)
    public List<Document> search(@RequestParam String query) {
        return searchService.search(query);
    }
}
```

When I do a search: **localhost:8189/api/v1/fias/search?query=Moscow** I get an error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.data.util.TypeInformation.isSubTypeOf(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z

The error occurs on the line (***SearchServiceImpl.java:23***): **List  all = addressElasticRepository.findByFullAddressContains (query);**

How to fix it?

UPD: Full StackTrace

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.data.util.TypeInformation.isSubTypeOf(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.createCollectionForValue(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:675)
>   ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.BUILD-20200217.043541-321.jar:4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.readCollectionValue(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:362)
>   ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.BUILD-20200217.043541-321.jar:4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.readValue(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:345)
>   ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.BUILD-20200217.043541-321.jar:4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$ElasticsearchPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:876)
>   ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.BUILD-20200217.043541-321.jar:4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.readProperties(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:319)
>   ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.BUILD-20200217.043541-321.jar:4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.readEntity(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:267)
>   ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.BUILD-20200217.043541-321.jar:4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.read(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:247)
>   ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.BUILD-20200217.043541-321.jar:4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.mapDocument(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:220)
>   ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.BUILD-20200217.043541-321.jar:4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.read(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:188)
>   ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.BUILD-20200217.043541-321.jar:4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.lambda$read$1(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:169)
>   ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.BUILD-20200217.043541-321.jar:4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.read(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:170)
>   ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.BUILD-20200217.043541-321.jar:4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.search(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:244)
>   ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.BUILD-20200217.043541-321.jar:4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.query.ElasticsearchPartQuery.execute(ElasticsearchPartQuery.java:106)
>   ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.BUILD-20200217.043541-321.jar:4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.findByFullAddressContains(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:na]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:338)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
>   ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.findByFullAddressContains(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   ru.evolenta.server.service.impl.SearchServiceImpl.search(**SearchServiceImpl.java:23**)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   ru.evolenta.server.controller.SearchController.search(**SearchController.java:27**)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158)
>   ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126)
>   ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111)
>   ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:84)
>   ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   ru.evolenta.server.filters.SimpleCORSFilter.doFilter(SimpleCORSFilter.java:51)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:209)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [na:1.8.0_201]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [na:1.8.0_201]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]

**UPD 2**: Error in spring-data-commons version. The isSubTypeOf method appeared after version 2.2. If I upgrade, the application does not start, here is the stack trace:

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IMPORT_BEAN_NAME_GENERATOR    at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:78)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$0(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:360)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:359)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:328)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   ru.evolenta.server.CoreFiasApplication.main(CoreFiasApplication.java:21)
>   [classes/:na]

Comment: There should be more lines in the stack trace, specifically which refers to your code. Can you share a longer log?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Yes, anything! I updated my post and posted a full stackrace

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I see that in the TypeInformation class the isSubTypeOf method has appeared in spring-data-commons since version 2.2. But my version of ElasticSearch only starts with this version of spring-data-commons (2.1.10.RELEASE). What to do?

Comment: This answer helped me solve my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58371997/9312228

Comment: Did you eventually end up with fixing versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GiorgiTsiklauri Your tips helped me come to the right decision. I carefully read the stack trace and explored the dependencies of my version of Spring Boot. In Spring-boot-dependencies-2.0.0.RELEASE.pom lists version 5.6.8 for ElasticSearch (my version 7.4). I rewrote my code according to this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58371997/9312228. Everything worked for me! I needed a CustomElasticSearchConverter and an ElasticsearchRestTemplate configured with it.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

class CustomElasticSearchConverter extends MappingElasticsearchConverter {

    private CustomConversions conversions = new ElasticsearchCustomConversions(Collections.emptyList());

    CustomElasticSearchConverter(MappingContext<? extends ElasticsearchPersistentEntity<?>, ElasticsearchPersistentProperty> mappingContext) {
        super(mappingContext);
        setConversions(conversions);
    }

    CustomElasticSearchConverter(MappingContext<? extends ElasticsearchPersistentEntity<?>, ElasticsearchPersistentProperty> mappingContext, GenericConversionService conversionService) {
        super(mappingContext, conversionService);
        setConversions(conversions);
    }

    @Override
    protected <R> R readValue(@Nullable Object source, ElasticsearchPersistentProperty property,
                              TypeInformation<R> targetType) {

        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (source instanceof List) {
            return readCollectionValue((List) source, property, targetType);
        }

        return super.readValue(source, property, targetType);
    }

    private Object readSimpleValue(@Nullable Object value, TypeInformation<?> targetType) {

        Class<?> target = targetType.getType();

        if (value == null || target == null || ClassUtils.isAssignableValue(target, value)) {
            return value;
        }

        if (conversions.hasCustomReadTarget(value.getClass(), target)) {
            return getConversionService().convert(value, target);
        }

        if (Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(target)) {
            return Enum.valueOf((Class<Enum>) target, value.toString());
        }

        return getConversionService().convert(value, target);
    }


    private <R> R readCollectionValue(@Nullable List<?> source, ElasticsearchPersistentProperty property,
                                      TypeInformation<R> targetType) {

        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Collection<Object> target = createCollectionForValue(targetType, source.size());

        for (Object value : source) {

            if (isSimpleType(value)) {
                target.add(
                        readSimpleValue(value, targetType.getComponentType() != null ? targetType.getComponentType() : targetType));
            } else {

                if (value instanceof List) {
                    target.add(readValue(value, property, property.getTypeInformation().getActualType()));
                } else {
                    target.add(readEntity(computeGenericValueTypeForRead(property, value), (Map) value));
                }
            }
        }

        return (R) target;
    }

    private Collection<Object> createCollectionForValue(TypeInformation<?> collectionTypeInformation, int size) {

        Class<?> collectionType = collectionTypeInformation.isCollectionLike()//
                ? collectionTypeInformation.getType() //
                : List.class;

        TypeInformation<?> componentType = collectionTypeInformation.getComponentType() != null //
                ? collectionTypeInformation.getComponentType() //
                : ClassTypeInformation.OBJECT;

        return collectionTypeInformation.getType().isArray() //
                ? new ArrayList<>(size) //
                : CollectionFactory.createCollection(collectionType, componentType.getType(), size);
    }

    private ElasticsearchPersistentEntity<?> computeGenericValueTypeForRead(ElasticsearchPersistentProperty property,
                                                                            Object value) {

        return ClassTypeInformation.OBJECT.equals(property.getTypeInformation().getActualType())
                ? getMappingContext().getRequiredPersistentEntity(value.getClass())
                : getMappingContext().getRequiredPersistentEntity(property.getTypeInformation().getActualType());
    }

    private boolean isSimpleType(Object value) {
        return isSimpleType(value.getClass());
    }

    private boolean isSimpleType(Class<?> type) {
        return conversions.isSimpleType(type);
    }
}
```

My config:

```
@Bean
RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
    return new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(
            new HttpHost(host, port)
    ));
}

@Primary
@Bean
public ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchTemplate() {
    CustomElasticSearchConverter converter = new CustomElasticSearchConverter(new SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext(), createConversionService());
    return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(elasticsearchClient(), converter);
}

private DefaultConversionService createConversionService() {
    return new DefaultConversionService();
}
```

and launcher:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT is built against Spring Data Commons 2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. You should not use the older commons 2.1.10.RELEASE here.

Out of curiosity: Why do you use a `CustomElasticSearchConverter`?

As for the configuration, check https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.0.M3/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.rest.

And when doing custom configuration,

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class})
```

is the right way to go.

**Edit:**

spring-data-elasticsearch 4.0.0.BUILD_SNAPSHOT will not work with spring-data-commons 2.0.5. `RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.IMPORT_BEAN_NAME_GENERATOR` was introduced in Spring 5.2.

So spring-data-elasticsearch 4.0 needs spring-data-commons 2.3 and Spring 5.2.3. Not having these versions will lead to the errors you see.

Comment: The reason is simple: my Spring Boot has version 2.0.0. ElasticSearch version below 6 is available with this version. And Spring-commons-data version 2.0.5. And I can’t use a higher version of Spring Boot, because there are too many dependencies inside the project. At the same time, they require me to use the version of ElasticSearch 7.4. With spring-data-commons version 2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, my application crashes with java.lang.NoSuchFieldError error: IMPORT_BEAN_NAME_GENERATOR

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in your code is:

```
@Repository
public interface AddressElasticRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Address, String> {
    List<Address> findByFullAddressContains(String fullAddress);
}
```

Try it without `Contains` and then with `Containing`(instead of `Contains`).

Please see the Spring Data Elasticsearch [Query Creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods) and Spring Data JPA [Query Creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) documentations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried both options. The error is the same. I think the problem is mapping. More precisely, in the version of spring-data-commons. Because in version 2.1.10 there is no isSubTypeOf method. But upgrading to an earlier version does not help, since the application stops starting.

Comment: I just tried it locally and it worked. So, it didn't work even with `findByFullAddress` only? strange. `isSubTypeOf` is present after `2.2`. What it says exactly if you upgrade it? at least, official docs uses the `Containing` method suffix.

Comment: I updated my post again. The error is this: **java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IMPORT_BEAN_NAME_GENERATOR**

Comment: Keep on that way, and see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58727497/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-import-bean-name-generator#comment103746978_58727497

Try to fix versions (maybe update some older ones).

Comment: I am using Spring Boot version 2.0.0.RELEASE and Spring 5.0.4. If I remove versions with spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch and spring-data-commons, then spring-data-commons version 2.0.5 is pulled. And the application crashes with an error: IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods! This is some kind of curse ...